# Ubuntu 12.10 Broadcom Wireless Won't Work

Tags: 12.10, wireless, broadcom, acer

Okay, I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 today, replacing Windows 8 and erasing all of my files (correctly, I hope. Darn Windows 8), and I was having some fun with it. I entered some code into the grub to be able to change my screen brightness (it was only one line and nothing went wrong), and was about to reboot until a message appeared on my screen saying I had 300-something updates to install.

Since I had heard users say to do this with a fresh install, I clicked Install, and rebooted my computer. Before that, my wireless worked fine. Once it booted back up, everything seemed to work as I had hoped it would; I could adjust the brightness, I could browse my computer, etc. One thing that didn't work, however, was my wireless internet.

When I click on the internet icon in my toolbar, it says that I am disconnected from a wired network, Enable Networking is on, and there's nothing to do with wireless connections in the menu (except VPN connections). I then hooked it up to the internet with an Ethernet cable, and it wouldn't connect to that either.

My internet works fine for everything else in my house, just not my laptop. What it looks like is that my laptop thinks I need to be connected to a wired connection and that I'm disconnected, because there's no "Wireless" tab in my network settings, only "Wired" and "Network Proxy".

I have an Acer Aspire E1-431-2644 laptop with a Broadcom BCM4314 Wireless LAN Controller. Someone please help!

Comment: Please read here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the same adapter in my Compaq laptop.  I've had a lot of trouble with upgrades over the years.  This article was very helpful when I upgraded to 12.10: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx

It seems all I needed to do was specify to use the b43 driver, so if you want to test whether this is the issue for you, open up a terminal window, and type:

```
modprobe b43
```

If this works you may want to follow the article's directions on adding the driver permanently.

Good Luck!